# content type is returned as text/html while the expected is application/json

Tags: node.js, cloudflare, cors, json, endpoint

some endpoints are returning the content type as text/html while the expected is application/json causing CORS error in the client side. when requesting from my localhost or from the server's IP address, the data is returned as expected. which means that the problem occurs from cloudflare.
i am using portzilla to route traffic on the domain name to the required port to access the server-side code. i tried specifying the content type header in portzilla, however, the same behaviour happened.

is any more information needed to provide better assistance?

Comment: since you didn't provide any information about the configuration and environment as also the Webservers used, is the mime type(s) correctly configured?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.